# TelegramReferral Bot

Tags: python, telegram

Hello I find a open source code on github and I edit is as myself but it doesn't work properly.

script work well untill I try to verify that members enter the channel that I shared with them.

it always seems like client doesn't getting user's information or script can't use that user's information correctly.

any help would be appreciate. thanks.

```
    try:
        bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)
        return True
    except ApiTelegramException as e:
        if e.result_json['description'] == 'Bad Request: user not found':
            return False
```

this is how I get **chat_id** and **user_id**

```
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "start_reg":  # pressed button start
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, const.START_REG, reply_markup=kbrd_sub)
    if call.data == "check_sub":  # pressed button "check sub"
        sub_to_text = "Sorry, you haven't signed up yet."
        if not check_sub('@interaliex', call.message.chat.id):
            sub_to_text = sub_to_text + "@interaliex"
            not_subscribed = True

        if not_subscribed:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, sub_to_text, reply_markup=kbrd_sub)
        else:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, const.FINISH_REG, parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=kbrd_final)
```

And this is how I check the member's status.

This is whole original code:https://github.com/asafheybetli/Referral/blob/main/rfrrl

in original code it has this call:

```
    if bot.get_chat_member(channel, user_id).status == 'left':
        return False
    return True
```

And with this call I am getting this error:

"A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: user not found"

Comment: Welcome! For best results, please be sure to share all relevant code (bot/call class definitions, etc.) , as well as any error messages/stack traces available.

Comment: thanks, have a look again sir I updated. with original call I get error, but with upper one it works but it awlays give same respond, doesn't matter that user in channel or not.

Comment: Are you certain that this user still exists on Telegram? (not only in/not in the channel)

Comment: sure that user is from my other TG account, I am trying to do with that account, trying to participiate with type /start to the bot, then bot shows me other buttons that contain "participiate" I press it and bot shows me the channel links and "Verify" button.
than I press verify it always shows me same message doesn't matter if I in those channel or not.